# Rotate an arrow in HTML from a specific point

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've figured out how to draw an arrow and rotate it:

```
     .arrow:after {
       content: "";
       display: inline-block !important;
       width: 0;
       height: 0;
       border-left: 8px solid white;
       border-top: 8px solid transparent;
       border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
       vertical-align: middle;

     }

     .arrow:before {
       width: 75px;
       height: 2px;
       background: white;
       content: "";
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: middle;
     }


   <div style="transform: rotate(-60deg)";><span class="arrow"></span></div>
```

But it rotates around the center, whereas I would want it to rotate from the bottom, for example, if you imagine an arrow at coordinates (0,0), I want it to always start at (0,0) but vary its endpoint.

In [this link](http://oreillymedia.github.io/svg-essentials-examples/ch06/rotate-center.html) they manage it with one arrow but I can't seem to only get the one rotating arrow.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: So... set the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) to whatever you need it to be? Lots of good tutorials about the fundamentals of CSS transforms on the web, any of them would have covered that part of transforms? (Also, you probably don't want to set a `style` attribute, just write a new class and assign that to your div instead. Separate those technologies for much more efficient dev/debug work)

Comment: That semi colon is wrongly placed <div style="transform: rotate(-60deg)";><span class="arrow"></span></div>. It should be there at all.

Answer (score 0):

under `transform: rotate()` add:

```
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
```

then change the percentages till they match where you want the rotate point to be